# How to print out a specific numeric pattern

Tags: c

I just had a question about C. I have a file that has text in the format of:

```
7034327874
5408438437
3267239807
1824566789
```

I was wondering how I would read in the data and in another file, print out:

```
703-432-7874
540-843-8437
326-723-9807
182-456-6789
```

Comment: Consider what you will do with the input `0824566789`. Are these telephone numbers?

Comment: One simple way would be to read each line with `fgets` and output 3 characters, `'-'`, 3 more characters, `'-'`, 4 last characters,

Comment: Smacks of homework - show us how you are doing it and ask a question about any specific problems.  "Do my homework for me" is for a different site.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider these numbers as *strings* of characters (each character happens to be a digit). Then do character processing on them.

For example:

```
char str[16];
memset (str, 0, sizeof(str));
if (scanf(" %15[0-9]", &str) > 0) 
  printf("%.3s", str);
```

should, if fed with `0734327574`, output `073` (notice that your example don't explain what should have happened in that case, and I am *guessing* one way of doing it. My guess could be wrong if `0734327574` is actually meant as an *octal* number for the decimal number 124891004).

The rest is an exercise to the reader. Of course you need to *carefully* read the documentation of [memset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset), of [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), of [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Don't forget to end `printf` format strings with `\n` or to call [fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) on `stdout` (which is often line-buffered).

Remember that [numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number) don't have digits. Only their notation have digits. The number [20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20_(number)), written in Roman notation *XX*, in English *twenty*, in French *vingt*, in hexadecimal `0x14`, in octal `024` (or even `24`<sub>8</sub>), in binary 10100, as the simple arithmetic expression 3*7-1, is still the same number (which happens to be twice the number of fingers I have on my hands, and is also the number of [arrondissements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrondissements_of_Paris) in Paris).